# Using the Azure Devops Server client library, how do you create the master branch in a new repository?

Tags: azure-devops, sdk

Using the client API I can create a new repository, but it hasn't been initialized and so doesn't contain a master branch.

```
public void CreateRepository(string name)
{
    TeamProjectReference tpr = new TeamProjectReference();

    tpr.Name = "AppDev";
    tpr.Id = new Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");

    GitRepositoryCreateOptions grco = new GitRepositoryCreateOptions();
    grco.ProjectReference = tpr;
    grco.Name = name;

    newRepo = gitClient.CreateRepositoryAsync(grco).Result;

}
```

I can't figure out how to create a master branch.  The methods to create branches all require a parent branch to create from.  How do I create master using the client libraries?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Please check if my answer helps :)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I create master using the client libraries?

Apart from creating the **empty** repo, you also need to initialize it with initial commit. Hint from this rest api [Initial commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/Pushes/Create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#initial-commit-(create-a-new-branch)), and also from this [official document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/Git/PushesSample.cs#L70). You can follow my **working sample** below:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Connect to Azure Devops Service and create an empty git repo.
            ConnectToAzureDevopsService(OrgUrl, PAT);
            TeamProjectReference teamProjectReference = new TeamProjectReference();
            teamProjectReference.Name = "MyProjectName";
            teamProjectReference.Id = new Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
            GitRepositoryCreateOptions gitRepositoryCreateOptions = new GitRepositoryCreateOptions();
            gitRepositoryCreateOptions.ProjectReference = teamProjectReference;
            gitRepositoryCreateOptions.Name = "MyTestRepo";
            GitRepository gitRepo = GitClient.CreateRepositoryAsync(gitRepositoryCreateOptions).Result;
            
            //You need extra steps below to initialize your newly created repo.

            //Craft the branch and commit that we'll push.
            GitRefUpdate newBranch = new GitRefUpdate()
            {
                RepositoryId = gitRepo.Id,
                Name = $"refs/heads/master",
                OldObjectId = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            };
            string newFileName = $"README.md";
            GitCommitRef newCommit = new GitCommitRef()
            {
                Comment = "Initial the repo with custom README.md",
                Changes = new GitChange[]
                {
                    new GitChange()
                    {
                        ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Add,
                        Item = new GitItem() { Path = $"/{newFileName}" },
                        NewContent = new ItemContent()
                        {
                            Content = "# Thank you for using VSTS!",
                            ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText,
                        },
                    }
                },
            };

            //Start initializing the repo via creating the push.
            GitPush InitialPush = GitClient.CreatePushAsync(new GitPush()
            {
                RefUpdates = new GitRefUpdate[] { newBranch },
                Commits = new GitCommitRef[] { newCommit },
            }, gitRepo.Id).Result;
            //Let me know if it succeeds.
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
```

**The result:**

[image]

Let me know if it helps.